# Точность чисел

Tags: python

Записываю в txt-файл ряд чисел, после запятой остаются 15 цифр, хотя в числе их больше 20.
Таким образом записываю в файл:

```
f = open('ko.txt','w')
for item in sn:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
f.close()
```

Как сделать, чтобы числа полностью записывались?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используются стандартные спецификаторы, к примеру для вывода числа с плавающей точкой используется %f, к нему можно указать и точность, в Вашем коде будет так:

```
f.write("%.20f" % item)
```

где 20 - количество знаков после запятой.